# Infinite Loop in spring security login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC 3.1.0 web application, and I am implementing Spring Security for the first time.

**secure-config.xml:**

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/lhome" access="ROLE_USER" />  

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/WEB-INF/views/403.jsp"/> 

    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp" always-use-default-target="true"/>

    <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_GUEST" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/home"/> 
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" >
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customMongoSecurityService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

I am using AJAX based login. When I give correct credentials or hit `/lhome` it redirects to the `/login` page instead of the home page.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please provide log. I think authentication failef

Answer (score 1):

Once Spring grants you an access, it will return your request with a session key. You will need to carry the session key for the subsequent requests.

Or you can configure the Spring to use http basic

```
 <http>
     ...
     <http-basic/>
 </http>
```

By this way, you have to send the user name and password over for each request (less secure for public web site).

Comment: sorry! but i was asking for why creating loop

Comment: My understanding of your question is, after you send in the correct credential in the 1st request, you are still re-directed to the log-in page in the 2nd request, and that makes you think you are stuck in the loop. That's why you have to either carry the session key or credential for subsequent requests. Hope my understanding is correct.

Comment: I think, it's a web application (pages and AJAX), not an external API (web service). The browser should carry session ID between requests automatically.

Comment: It's seems to problem solved.I was not using Qualifier to give alias name of AuthenticationManager class.thanks